# What ohm readings should be expected when testing the input terminals on a 3 speed blower motor that has been separated from all attachable wires

Tags: motor, ac, single-phase

GENTEQ ECM 3.0 MOTOR WITH MODULE
MODEL:5SME39SXL3019
1 PH    60/50 Hz    3/4HP    120/240 V
9.6/5.6 A    1050 RPM
Cust. Model 51-102603-01
GC09  [image: photo of imput terminals to row and power terminals bottom row]

Comment: WHat results did you measure?

Comment: That looks like a drive, so depending on the meter I'd expect to see open circuit, or charging capacitor to open circuit. https://unitedhvacmotors.com/product/ge-genteq-x13-bare-module-only-3-4-hp-for-motor-5sme39nxl3063-hd46ae126/